# Add item to array if Bool = false

Tags: swiftui

What i want to be able to do is to add items to an array if the Bool attached to them is true.

For example :
Here is my data model

```
struct ListModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var amount:Int
    var code:String
    var users:[User]
    var items:[Item]

}

struct User: Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id = UUID()
    var foreName:String
    var surName:String
    var username:String
    var pfp:String
}

struct Item:Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var image:String?
    var showItem:Bool
    var amount:String
}
```

and when an the property `showItem` is true i want to add it to a new array

I have tried an approach like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTest: View {
    
    var list:ListModel
    @State var nonHiddenItems:[Item] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<list.items.count){item in
                ItemView(item: list.items[item])
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            ForEach(0..<list.items.count){item in
                if list.items[item].showItem == true{
                    nonHiddenItems.append(list.items[item])
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListTest(list: ListModel(name: "Family Shopping", amount: 0, code: "1001", users: [User(foreName: "Elon", surName: "Musk", username: "Elon123", pfp: "Musk"), User(foreName: "Jeff", surName: "Bezos", username: "Jefferey", pfp: "Bezos")], items: [Item(name: "Cheese", image: "Pizza", showItem: true, amount: "5g"), Item(name: "Ham", showItem: false, amount: "5g")]))
    }
}
```

But i get errors such as  `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'` on my `ForEach loop`

How can i fix m errors?
Many Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 2):

A `ForEach` (uppercase) expression is a view builder, not a classic `for` loop. You cannot use `ForEach` in `onAppear`

Instead use `forEach` (lowercase)

```
(0..<list.items.count).forEach{ index in
    if list.items[index].showItem == true{
        nonHiddenItems.append(list.items[index])
    }
}
```

or *swiftier*

```
nonHiddenItems = list.items.filter(\.showItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ForEach(...)` in `.onAppear(...)` like you do.

I suggest you read the basics of SwiftUI here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Try this approach:

```
struct ListTest: View {
    var list: ListModel
    @State var nonHiddenItems:[Item] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(list.items){ item in  // <-- here
                ItemView(item: item)
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            for i in list.items.indices {   // <-- here
                if list.items[i].showItem {
                    nonHiddenItems.append(list.items[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: my guess is, what you probably wanted to do, is this:

```
struct ListTest: View {
    var list: ListModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(list.items.filter{$0.showItem}){ item in
                ItemView(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you do not "duplicate" your source of truth array in `ListModel`.